# What happens when an exception occurs in JMS listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-jms

I am using Default Message Listener Container. I have set session transacted property true in configuration.

My `onMessage()` method is this:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        // Some code here
    } catch (JmsException jmse) {
        log.error(jmse);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error(t);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am handling the exception in a `catch` block.

My requirement is that if it is a JMS Exception, it should be resent, i.e. message redelivered to the listener/consumer as it happens when there is transaction rollback. How can that happen?

Can we manually rollback the transaction here? I think that is a possible solution but I dont how to do that in code.

Another generic question:

Since I am handling all the possible exceptions through a `catch` block, I guess there will not be a scenario of message redelivery i.e. transaction rollback since I am handling all the possible exceptions through the `catch` block. Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a `SessionAwareMessageListener`; simply throw the exception instead of catching it and the container will rollback the delivery.

Specifically, it will rollback if the exception is a `JmsException`, `RuntimeException` (or subclasses) or an `Error`.

You should generally not catch `Throwable` anyway; it's not good practice.

**EDIT**

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        // Some code here
    } 
    catch (JmsException jmse) {
        log.error(jmse);
        // Do some stuff
        throw new RuntimeException(jmse); // JMSException is checked so can't throw
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error(e);
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(t);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I am using Throwable to catch, doesnt it catch every possible exception since throwable is the parent class of all exceptions and errors.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a good idea to "eat" `Throwable` - it could be an `Error` such as OOM. In any case, to force a rollback you'll have to wrap the `Throwable` in a `RuntimeException` because you can't re-throw it because the method signature doesn't allow it.

Comment: Can you demonstrate through code? I dont know how to implement what you are saying in code.

Comment: I have some logic in JMS exception block which needs to be executed before the rollback. Would your suggestion be still valid then?

Comment: See the edit; the rollback doesn't happen until the exception is thrown.

Comment: So I believe this will handle the logic and after that it will start a rollback and the message will be redelivered. Can you look at this question too regarding durable subscription https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490934/use-case-scenario-of-durable-listeners-consumers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SessionAwareMessageListener ? Please check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SessionAwareMessageListener.html)

Comment: What does it do ? So currently my class implements message listener, now it has to implement sessionawaremessagelistener, right?

Comment: Also I have to acknowledge manually through session object and call a rollback in catch block through session object when necessary. I believe this is how you are saying I should implement it.

Comment: since you get a session object here in this interface you can rollback or commit the transactions as per your requirement.